# Remove dimming view behind UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to remove the dimming view behind a popover presented using UIPopoverPresentationController. I've implemented a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get rid of this dimming view.

I've tracked the dimming view to a "_UIMirrorNinePatchView" using the view hierarchy inspector, but there's no good way of removing it short of crawling through the subviews of UIWindow and manually removing this view from its superview. This approach is flawed as it briefly flashes the dimming view before it's removed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My workarounds if someone still needed (as myself trying to implement custom blur in popupVC):

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController { 
private let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterialDark)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .clear

    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurView.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(blurView)
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    popoverPresentationController?.containerView?.removeAllBluresExept(customBlure: blurEffect)
}} 
private extension UIView {
func removeAllBluresExept(customBlur: UIBlurEffect) {
    subviews.forEach {
        if let visualEffectView = $0 as? UIVisualEffectView,
           visualEffectView.effect is UIBlurEffect, visualEffectView.effect != customBlur {
            // System Apple white blure view heeds to hide
            $0.isHidden = true
        }
        if !$0.subviews.isEmpty {
            $0.removeAllBluresExept(customBlure: customBlur)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Set the `backgroundColor` property to `.clear`

`popOverPresentationController.backgroundColor = .clear`

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. Also, the documentation states that this property sets the backgroundColor of the Popover itself, not that of the dimmingView.